# Using credentials from Jenkins store in a jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I made a multibranch pipeline project in Jenkins. I need to use two repositories and both need credentials.

I created a Jenkinsfile in repository1:

```
node ('label1'){
  stage 'sanity check'
  sh 'echo sanity check'
  stage 'checkout other repository'
  checkout([
      $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
      userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository2.git'],[credentialsId:'23b2eed1-2863-49d5-bc7b-bcccb9ad914d']]
  ])
  stage 'log results'
  sh 'echo result = OK'
 }
```

When I push this file onto a branch of repository1 and start the build I get the following error in Jenkins:

```
Branch indexing
Setting origin to https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository1.git
Fetching origin...
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository1.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository1.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git config --local credential.username BRNTZN # timeout=10
 > git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git1367320661933193799.credentials # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository1.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
Checking out Revision d997a29e9d1f639d56eb425ec00e03309e099c7a (jenkinsfilebranch1)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f d997a29e9d1f639d56eb425ec00e03309e099c7a
 > git rev-list f81d0d366fd751857a2640c587817f4d047a15af # timeout=10
[Pipeline] node
Running on jenkins agent (i-07353fc08cb42f10e) in /var/jenkins/workspace/multiBranch/jenkinsfilebranch1
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage (sanity check)
Entering stage sanity check
Proceeding
[Pipeline] sh
[jenkinsfilebranch1] Running shell script
+ echo sanity check
sanity check
[Pipeline] stage (checkout other repository)
Entering stage checkout other repository
Proceeding
[Pipeline] checkout
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository2.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository2.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository2.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository2.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:799)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1055)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1086)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository2.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org/BRNTZN/repository2.git/'

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1723)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1459)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at ......remote call to jenkins agent (i-07353fc08cb42f10e)(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:797)
    ... 13 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

The credentials should be correct:

[image]

And using those credentials for that repository in a freestyle project gives no error:

[image]

**Update**

I created a freestyle project using SSH credentials and added that public key to my Bitbucket account to test if I can make SSH work:

[image: freestylecredentials SSH]

This worked:

```
    Started by user admin
Building remotely on jenkins agent (i-039385e75b60d70f7) (label1) in workspace /var/jenkins/workspace/gitcredentials test
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials jenkinsmaster key
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 1d51064143e7337cbc0b1910918166facc9c2330 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 1d51064143e7337cbc0b1910918166facc9c2330
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

However when updating the jenkinsfile in the following way:

```
node ('label1'){
  stage 'sanity check'
  sh 'echo sanity check'
  stage 'checkout other repository'
  checkout([
      $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
      userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git'],[credentialsId:'jenkinsmaster']]
  ])
  stage 'log results'
  sh 'echo result = OK'
 }
```

I still get the same error:

```
Started by user admin
Setting origin to git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository1.git
Fetching origin...
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository1.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository1.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials jenkinsmaster key
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository1.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Checking out Revision 29fc47911827d829f5abe9456bd8df78bc478fe7 (jenkinsfilebranch1)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 29fc47911827d829f5abe9456bd8df78bc478fe7
 > git rev-list 29fc47911827d829f5abe9456bd8df78bc478fe7 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] node
Running on jenkins agent (i-039385e75b60d70f7) in /var/jenkins/workspace/multiBranch/jenkinsfilebranch1
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage (sanity check)
Entering stage sanity check
Proceeding
[Pipeline] sh
[jenkinsfilebranch1] Running shell script
+ echo sanity check
sanity check
[Pipeline] stage (checkout other repository)
Entering stage checkout other repository
Proceeding
[Pipeline] checkout
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:799)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1055)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1086)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1723)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1459)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at ......remote call to jenkins agent (i-039385e75b60d70f7)(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1180.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:797)
    ... 13 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct credentialsId ? Also, consider using SSH URL for your Git connection instead of HTTP URL

Comment: @Pom12 I'm pretty sure it's correct, I updated the question with pictures.

Comment: Instead of cut-n-pasting "hard-coded" credentials ID into Pipeline scripts, I've taken to adding a Credentials Parameter to the job, that defaults to the known-good one. Then in the script, `credentialsId: "${git_credentials}"`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your GitSCM class instantiation is incorrect. You have created two UserRemoteConfig objects - one with a URL of 'git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git' and one with a credentialsId of 'jenkinsmaster'. Instead you want one object with both properties set.

```
checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git'],[credentialsId:'jenkinsmaster']]
])
```

Should be:

```
checkout([
  $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git',credentialsId:'jenkinsmaster']]
])
```

Notice there are no brackets around the comma in the "userRemoteConfigs" section in the second case.

I had just ran into the same issue and connected up an Eclipse debugger to Jenkins to find the issue.

See *[git-plugin GitSCM does not support ssh credentials when using checkout in a Jenkinsfile](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45007)* (45007).

Comment: Look carefully at where the [ ]'s are. In the first one there are two [ ] blocks inside the userRemoteConfigs block and in the second there is only one.

Comment: @MarkRx, that information would be good to have in the your original answer.  I looked for 5 minutes before I noticed the subtle difference.

Answer (score 7):

I've had the exact same issue: checkout using credentials in a freestyle project works fine, checkout in a shell (as the `jenkins` user) works fine, and checkout in the pipeline fails. I've updated Jenkins + plugins to the latest version.

I finally managed to get it to work by placing the correct key in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa. It looks like the GitSCM plugin completely ignores the provided credentialsId, and just uses the key in `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa`. I generated a keypair without passphrase for this.

It is a workaround, and I suspect that GitSCM has a bug, but at least you can use the pipeline plugin.

Comment: Did all of this happen on master for you or did you also perform the build on a separate slave instance? Because I tried what you did but can't get it to work.

Comment: When creating keys on the slave and then adding that public key to bitbucket it fixed my problem. I will just have to make sure that every slave uses the same public key and I guess I'm good to go.

Comment: @BRNTZN This was on master, I did not check the behaviour on slave nodes.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of credentials do you use?

I suggest that you use SSH credentials (i.e. private/public keys):

1. [Generate](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-an-ssh-key-to-an-account-302811853.html) a SSH key pair (make sure you generate it for the correct username!)
2. Add your public [SSH key to your Bitbucket account](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-an-ssh-key-to-an-account-302811853.html)
3. Configure your Jenkins to use your newly created SSH private key, as shown in the example below:

[image]

Then you need to use SSH URL as connection to your Git your credentials in your pipeline (instead of HTTP URL), as follows:

```
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url:'ssh://BRNTZN@bitbucket.org:BRNTZN/repository2.git'],[credentialsId:'jenkins_ssh_key']]
])
```

Also, note that you might want to set a specific id for your credentials (e.g. `jenkins_ssh_key` or `BRNTZN_ssh_key`) to improve readability and simplify pipeline configuration.

Comment: Can jenkins use the ssh key if it's placed on my master? Or do I need to make it available on every single slave I start?

Comment: I'm not so sure and don't want to say something stupid but I'd say that Jenkins will make your credentials available to all your nodes, regardless of what node is currently executing your pipeline, because the option specifies `From a file on Jenkins master`

Comment: Updated op with an ssh attempt.

Comment: Please check : 1/ That you have added your SSH public key to your Bitbucket account. 2/ That you use the correct user to connect to Bitbucket. Here you use `git` user (as shown in your command `git@gitbucket.org...` where you should use the user associated with your SSH keys (check your public key to see which user you generated it for). It should probably be `jenkins@gitbucket.org...` or `BRNTZN@gitbucket.org...`

Comment: Since I used the same credentials and url in the freestyle project and it ended up working does that not prove that the credentials are correct?

Answer (score 2):

Scenario, checkout repo A using HTTPS then in a fastlane file checkout repos B and C with HTTPS in two separate stages and push commits to branches in repos B and C using git commands in a fastlane fastfile.  In a pipeline Jenkinsfile partial environment and steps only below:

```
    environment {
        GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN = credentials("unique-credential-github-pat")
        GIT_REPO_B = "https://unique-credential-github-pat:${GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/organization_name/repository_name.git"
        GIT_REPO_C = "https://unique-credential-github-pat:${GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/organization_name/repository_name.git"
    }

    stage (B) {   
       steps {
          checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "myname/branch_name"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'GitLFSPull'],[$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 1, noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: true]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'unique-credential-github-pat', url: GIT_REPO_B]]])
       }
     }

     stage (C) {   
        steps {
           checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "myname/branch_name"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'GitLFSPull'],[$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 1, noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: true]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'unique-credential-github-pat', url: GIT_REPO_C]]])
        }
     }
```

Commands used in fastlane fastfile lane:

```
sh ('git add file_to_add.txt')
sh ('git commit -m "Commit file text"')
sh ('git remote -v')
sh ('git push origin myname/branch_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Pipeline plugin tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#creating-multibranch-projects), for a multibranch project, you don't have to specify the repository in the node. Just use `checkout scm`.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work with multiple repositories as the original poster requested, as multibranch assume a given repository.  If this does work, please describe how.