# Jenkins scm step fails unexpectedly

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I seem to be having a strange issue with the pipeline i have arranged.
The steps to reproduce:

1. Jenkins is installed, authentication granted, plugins installed, etc.
2. Create a new pipeline
3. Add a new 'Pipeline script from SCM' step
4. Select 'git' as the repo type
5. Provide the repo url (using git user)

Expected: Repo accessed without any issues.
Actual: Repo access fails with the following error:

"Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h git@git.assembla.com:[repo-name].git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

Note: invoking the same line from the PowerShell completes without error and I'm able to fetch the code locally.

Any ideas what's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use SSH credentials to connect to your Git repository.
To know how to define new SSH credentials, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39467055/702954), which is summarized by the capture below :

[image: Defining SSH credentials for Jenkins]

Once you have added credentials with a private/public to both your Jenkins and your distant repository, you can update your `pipeline script from SCM` to use your credentials, as example below shows :

[image: Use SSH credentials in a pipeline job]

Comment: That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> invoking the same line from the PowerShell

Did you invoke it using the same user account as Jenkins ?

(and I guess you did, but just to be sure : from the same machine ?)

Comment: I invoked it from the same machine.
How can I be sure that Jenkins actually uses the same credentials?

Comment: The CD server is Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Is Jenkins launched as a service ? If so : go check this service's configuration