# Checkout a tag in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Tried using

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', 
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: '${repoURL}']], 
  branches: [[name: 'refs/tags/${tag-version}']]],poll: false
```

This fails with an Authentication error. Is there any way other than using

> withCredentials

to checkout tag in a Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After spending, hours got here

Correct way to use GitSCM in declarative pipeline is

`checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: repoURL, credentialsId: credential]], branches: [[name: tag-version]]],poll: false`

Not like I found in most places in web

`checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: repoURL], [credentialsId: credential]], branches: [[name: tag-version]]],poll: false`

Answer (score 2):

I would expect it to work like a normal branch, Have you tried without the 'refs/tags/' prefix?

Comment: [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-general-scm) says 
<tagName>
This does not work since the tag will not be recognized as tag.
Use refs/tags/<tagName> instead.
E.g. git-2.3.0
refs/tags/<tagName>
Tracks/checks out the specified tag.
E.g. refs/tags/git-2.3.0

Answer (score 2):

I also have to quote the credential id

```
stage('checkout') {
    steps {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: tagVersion]],
                  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'ssh://git@repo',
                                       credentialsId: 'my-user-id']]
                ])
        }
    }
```

**Annoation**

'my-user-id' is the id of the entry you will find on the credentials page.

But it's **not** the title you see in the dropdown select box in the gui.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication error has nothing to do with the tag - seems like 2 different issues.

You should add a `credentialId` to the `userRemoteConfigs` part, as such:

`checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', 
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: '${repoURL}'], [credentialsId: '${credential}']], 
  branches: [[name: '${tag-version}']]],poll: false`

Also, you can use the following format for variables:

`checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', 
  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: repoURL], [credentialsId: credential]], 
  branches: [[name: tag-version]]],poll: false`

Comment: I was trying to use the same but without credentialId.

Comment: You must autheniticed it in some way

Comment: `returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed ` Same error even after adding the credential ID.
` checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: repo_url], [credentialsId: credential]], branches: [[name: tag_version]]]`

Used the same credentialID for the user used for initial Checkout. I got the credentialID from https://jenkins/credentials/

Comment: Looks like the issue here is with Authentication in GitSCM. Something similar to  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451345/using-credentials-from-jenkins-store-in-a-jenkinsfile)

Comment: Finally, see what worked. I was using a wrong syntax for credentialsId. I had to use `[[url: repo_url, credentialsId: '****']]` where I was using `[[url: repoURL], [credentialsId: credential]]`

Answer (score 0):

If one don't want to fiddle around with the cryptic syntax, I've been using this solution to switch to a dedicated tag or branch, especially if it's a job parameter and not clear if the given value is a branch or a tag:

```
git(
    credentialsId: '<your-cred-id>',
    url: "<your-repo-url>"
)
sh(script:"""
    git checkout \$(git rev-parse --verify ${GIVEN_BRANCH_OR_TAG})
""")
```

The result will be in detached head mode but for most cases that's not a problem anyway.