# Jenkins groovy - How to check out specific tag?

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

To checkout latest commit from specific branch I use code below:

```
treeMapData = git(branch: branchName, credentialsId: credential, url: "${gitLabServer}/${projectName}/${repo}.git")
```

---

How to checkout specific tag commit in scripted pipeline?

Comment: @Sers I need your help on this

Answer (score 0):

Seems similar to that question : [Checkout a tag in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241980/checkout-a-tag-in-jenkins-pipeline)

Try this code :

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "${gitLabServer}/${projectName}/${repo}.git", credentialsId: credential]], branches: [[name: tag-version]]],poll: false
```